# How to apply data types from table A to each dictionary B in q?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with ~5m rows and 100 columns of various data types. For some rows the column value may not be populated, e.g. the value is an empty symbol.

I'm serializing the records from this table into json using `.j.j`. When I do this only the columns for each row that are populated get copied over.

When the json records are deserialized back to kdb using `.j.k` 2 things happen; (*1*) all data types are now strings and (*2*) each dictionary has a different length depending on which columns were populated in the original table.

What I'd like to be able to do is take the meta from `table A` (the original table) and then, after deserializing the json records, apply those data formats to the deserialized dictionaries. An example of what my `table A` looks like...

```
    q)minroe
    id version symbol source nbb
    ----------------------------
    L  "0.1"   ARCH   A      1
    F  "0.1"   ARDI          1
    U  "0.1"   AREJ   B      0
    W  "0.1"   ARFH   B      1
    G  "0.1"   ARGI   A      0

    q)meta minroe
    c      | t f a
    -------| -----
    id     | c
    version| C
    symbol | s
    source | s
    nbb    | b
```

An example of what two of the 5 dictionaries created after deserializing the json file created from `table A` would look like (rows 1 and 2 shown)...

```
    q)dict1
    id     | "L"
    version| "0.1"
    symbol | "ARCH"
    source | "A"
    nbb    | "1"

    q)dict2
    id     | "F"
    version| "0.1"
    symbol | "ARDI"
    nbb    | "0"
```

What I'd like is a function that can turn the values of dict1 and dict2 into their original data format from `table A`. Desired output would look like the following...

```
    q)json1
    id     | L
    version| "0.1"
    symbol | `ARCH
    source | `A
    nbb    | 1b

    q)json2
    id     | F
    version| "0.1"
    symbol | `ARDI
    nbb    | 0b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

```
// define the table
q)minroe:([]id:`L`F;version:("0.1";"0.1");symbol:`ARCH`ARDI;source:`A`;nbbo:11b)

// get dicts from json and back
q)json1:.j.k .j.j first minroe
q)json2:.j.k .j.j last minroe

// .j.k will give you back floats, bools. We will want to keep them as is
// .j.k will give you strings back otherwise. For string columns (C)
// we will want to keep as is
q)d:"fbC"!"fb*"

// define dictionary of cast statements
q)m:exec raze {if[x in "fbC";:()];enlist[y]!enlist ($;upper[x]^d x;y)}'[t;c] from meta minroe

// simple functional update using the dict created above
q)f:{![x;();0b;inter[key x;key m]#m]}

// results
q)f json1
id     | `L
version| "0.1"
symbol | `ARCH
source | `A
nbbo   | 1b
q)f json2
id     | `F
version| "0.1"
symbol | `ARDI
source | `
nbbo   | 1b

// if you want prot-eval around the cast statements, you can do that too
// just redefine m to utilise prot-eval (.)
q)m:exec raze {if[x in "fbC";:()];enlist[y]!enlist (.;$;(enlist;upper[x]^d x;y);y)}'[t;c] from meta minroe

// f will continue to work except if a cast fails for some reason it'll fall back to resuting in the string data

HTH,
Sean
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Can you clarify what this part of the function is doing "($;upper[x]^d x;y)". I believe it's for changing the data format of the dictionaries values but I'm not clear on the purpose of the leading "$", where the variable (value?) d is from, or the purpose of the trailing x;y (at the end). Thanks for the help and additional clarification.

Comment: Hi marrowgari, I've edited the answer to include d. d is just a dictionary of the float, bool, and string casting methods as they are typed outputs from .j.k. Apologies for omitting that.`($;upper[x]^d x;y)` is a parse tree meaning, index into d at x, fill with upper x, and cast y with that resulting value. Essentially `(upper[x]^d[x]) $ y`. You can see how a parse tree is created by using `parse` - e.g. `q)-1 raze -3!parse "\"x\"$\"y\"";` will show you why it is written like this